# Does rappid Joint js have the ability to save and reload a graph from JSON with layout intact

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I am trying to evaluate if the rappid library will allow me to create my diagram, save it to JSON format and then re-load it from the same to view and edit later wihtout changing the layout. Any suggestions / tips from anyone who has used this library would be greatly appreciated.
https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.1/joint.html#dia.Graph.JSON 
does not specify this
https://www.jointjs.com/#Rappid-More-Info

Answer (score 2):

`graph.fromJSON` / `graph.toJSON` is what you're looking for.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(graph)
// ... send jsonString to the server, 
// store it to the localStorage or do whatever you want
// ... later on
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(jsonString))
```